# Limit results per column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very big database that looks like this (3m rows)

```
+-----------+----------------+-------+
|  Category |   SubCategory  | Count |
+-----------+----------------+-------+
|  cat1     |   green        | 200   |
|  cat1     |   blue         | 215   |
|  cat1     |   red          | 20    |
|  cat2     |   something    | 540   |
|  cat2     |   chicken      | 100   |
|  cat2     |   dog          | 33    |
|  cat3     |   ball         | 404   |
|  cat3     |   bed          | 777   |
|  cat4     |   shoes        | 72    |
|  cat4     |   green        | 14    |
|  cat4     |   red          | 2     |
|  cat4     |   panda        | 4     |
+-----------+----------------+-------+
```

How can I sort by Count then grab the top 100 results of cat1, then the top 100 results of cat2 and so on.

Comment: Also. forgot to mention that that table is the result of another query and it's grouped by Category and subcategory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to establish a `row_number` per group and then filter accordingly.  With `mysql`, you'll need to use `user-defined variables`:

```
select category, subcategory, `count`
from (
    select *, 
         ( 
            case category 
            when @curCategory 
            then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            else @curRow := 1 AND @curCategory := category end
          ) + 1 AS rank
    from yourtable cross join (select @curRow:=0, @curCategory:='') c
    order by category, `count` desc
) t
where rank <= 100
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e36f/1)

Comment: Thanks, would this scan through all the 3 million records?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by an inner join and group by.

Note: I changed `count` to `count1`. It is always a good practice not to use db reserved keywords in query.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4de67/1)**</kbd>

```
SELECT category,
       subcategory,
       count1
FROM
  (SELECT t1.category,
          max(t1.subcategory) AS subcategory,
          max(t1.count1) AS count1,
          count(t1.count1) AS rnk
   FROM tbl t1
   INNER JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.category=t2.category
   AND t1.count1<=t2.count1
   GROUP BY t1.category,
            t1.count1) cnt
WHERE rnk <=100
```

The inner query is working like `rank over partition by` and assigning `rank` by `count1 desc` group by `category`. Its output will be something like

```
+----------+-------------+--------+-----+
| category | subcategory | count1 | rnk |
+----------+-------------+--------+-----+
| cat1     | red         |     20 |   3 |
| cat1     | green       |    200 |   2 |
| cat1     | blue        |    215 |   1 |
| cat2     | dog         |     33 |   3 |
| cat2     | chicken     |    100 |   2 |
| cat2     | something   |    540 |   1 |
```

Then you can get top 100 rows by outer query.

Comment: Thanks, would this scan through all the 3 million records?

Comment: Yes. If you have fewer `category` and more records per `categroy`, I would suggest you to create a procedure. In it, pass the table as `order by category, count1 desc` and use a counter to count first 100 rows per category and insert those into a tmp table. And then display that tmp table.